# Pass method as parameter and use that method on an object (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript function that receives a method, and calls that method on an object created inside the function.

```
const callMethod = myMethod => {
    someObject.myMethod();
}
```

I need this because I want to make a function that makes an HTTP request via fetch, and specify which method to call after getting the response from the fetch, where the options are: .json(), .text(), .blob(), .formData() or .arrayBuffer()

This is my code:

```
const sendPost = (url, bodyObj) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const settings = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"},
                body: JSON.stringify(bodyObj)
            }
            let req = await fetch(url, settings);
            
            // Here I'm forcing the .json() method, I want it to be able to choose between .json(), .text(), etc. when calling this function:
            let res = await req.json();
            
            return resolve(res);
        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried this, but it didn't work:

```
const sendPost = (url, bodyObj, func) => {
    // ...
    let req = await fetch(url, settings);
    let res = await req.func();
    // ...
}

sendPost("some url", {some object}, Response.json); // TypeError: req.func is not a function
```

I think the easiest way to do this is to pass a string with the name of the method I want to use, and then decide which method I want to call using conditionals. But I would like something more robust, which allows passing the pointer to an actual method, since the content of a string can be misspelled.

Comment: Consider passing a callback instead. `someObject, response => response.json());` TypeScript (or, to a lesser extent, JSDoc) helps avoid misspelling typos too.

Comment: It depends on how the OP passes the information about the to be called/invoked method as parameter to the function. In case parameter `func` carries a string value like `'json'` or `'text'` then result will be processed like ... `let res = await req[func]();` ...but in case the OP passes real method references then a function's [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method is the to be chosen tool ... `let res = await func.call(req);` ...And in case one is not sure about `req` then ...`await req?.[func]?.()` for the former case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you *could* do this.

The way you've written it, if you were to pass in a string (`"json"`), then you could do this:

```
let response = await sendPost(..., "json");
```

```
    let res = await req[func]();
```

That finds the member with the name matching the string found in `func`.

You could also use a *callback*:

```
let json = await sendPost(..., response => response.json());
```

```
    let res = await func(req);
```

But the only thing you're doing after that point in your helper function is resolving errors and returning the result. It might make more sense to have your helper function return a Promise with the response in it.

```
let response = await sendPost(...);
let json = response.json();
```

```
    let res = await fetch(url, settings);
    return res;
```

Comment: It works well! But I got an error using `req.[func]()`. Considering Peter's comment, it's `req[func]()` (without the dot)

Comment: Yep, of course. Just a typo on my part. I fixed it.